# How do you add a JPanel to a JFrame, right before removing an old JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I want to use a JButton to delete the existing JPanel in the current JFrame, and then add a JPanel from another class into the current JFrame. (When I say current, I mean in the class I am currently in)

This may be better to explain with the code:

```
package gui; //CUSTOMIZATION MANDATORY FOR PROPER WORKING (ish)

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Initial_GUI { //gives questions (source not included, keylistener included (currently not working), actionlistener included)

private static String input;
private static String author = "Author";
private static String version = "v0.5.1";

static JFrame frame;
static JTextField textField;
static JLabel L1;

public static int i = 0;

public static void main(String args[]) {

    frame = new JFrame();

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    panel.setLayout(null);

    L1 = new JLabel("This is going to be replaced"); //max chars is 45
    L1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L1.setSize(1000, 20);
    L1.setLocation(50, 10);

    JLabel L2 = new JLabel("Author: " + author);
    L2.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
    L2.setLocation(280, 100);
    L2.setSize(200, 20);

    JLabel L3 = new JLabel(version);
    L3.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
    L3.setLocation(5, 100);
    L3.setSize(200, 20);

    JButton B1 = new JButton("Submit");
    B1.setSize(75, 25);
    B1.setLocation(260, 45);
    //add action listener

    B1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
              getReply(); //part of example
              L1.setText(input); //example end.
              i += 1;
              if(i == 5) {
                  frame.add(Results_GUI.panel);
                  frame.remove(panel);
              }

              //This is where to put the method(s) that will be called when the button is pressed
              //I advise to put a KeyListener in this class as well that listens for "enter" as another way to submit the answer
          } 
        } );



    textField = new JTextField(); //make show
    textField.setSize(200, 25); //size confirmed
    textField.setLocation(60, 45);
    textField.setVisible(true);


    panel.add(L1);
    panel.add(textField);
    panel.add(L2);
    panel.add(L3);
    panel.add(B1);
    panel.setVisible(true);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setTitle("Quiz Generator (Alpha)");

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    System.out.println(textField.getLocationOnScreen());
}

private boolean pressed = false;
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { //this needs to work to move on

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && pressed == false) {
        //enter the same code here as you have in your "actionPerformed" method
        getReply();
        L1.setText(input);
        pressed = true;
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        pressed = false;
    }
}

private static void getReply() {
    input = textField.getText();
    textField.setText(null); //working
}


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static void showResults() { //fix by changing what panel is displayed + changing the size of the JFrame
    if(input.equals("")) {
        frame.setSize(1000, 400);
    }
}
```

}

This is just a template I am attempting to create. **IGNORE THE KEYLISTENER FOR NOW**. In line 56 I am attempting to add the panel from another class. It is giving me a null pointer exception. If it is easier for you to help me, and others viewing this for the same problem, here is the other class' code:

```
package gui; //CUSTOMIZATION MANDATORY FOR PROPER WORKING (ish)

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Results_GUI { //Source not included, Maximum number of questions per quiz: 15 CHECK WITH SPACING (QUESTIONS CAN HAVE MAX CHARS OF 45)

/**
 * Information:
 *      In the "NEW" section, replace "author" with the results for the question (4 being question 1, and 19 being question 15) 
 */

public static String author = "Author";
public static String version = "v0.5.1";

static JFrame frame;
public static JPanel panel;
public static JLabel L1;

public static void main(String args[]) {


    frame = new JFrame();

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    panel.setLayout(null);

    L1 = new JLabel("RESULTS"); //keep
    L1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L1.setSize(1000, 20);
    L1.setLocation(245, 10);

    JLabel L2 = new JLabel("Author: " + author); //keep
    L2.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
    L2.setLocation(380, 950);
    L2.setSize(200, 20);

    JLabel L3 = new JLabel(version); //keep
    L3.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
    L3.setLocation(5, 950);
    L3.setSize(200, 20);


    /**              NEW STARTS HERE                      **/ /**              NEW STARTS HERE                      **/ /**              NEW STARTS HERE                      **/


    JLabel L4 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L4.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L4.setLocation(5, 40);
    L4.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L5 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L5.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L5.setLocation(5, 103);
    L5.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L6 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L6.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L6.setLocation(5, 166);  //completed
    L6.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L7 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L7.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L7.setLocation(5, 229);
    L7.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L8 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L8.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L8.setLocation(5, 292); 
    L8.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L9 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L9.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L9.setLocation(5, 355);
    L9.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L10 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L10.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L10.setLocation(5, 418); //completed
    L10.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L11 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L11.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L11.setLocation(5, 481);
    L11.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L12 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L12.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L12.setLocation(5, 544);
    L12.setSize(20000, 20);

    JLabel L13 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L13.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L13.setLocation(5, 607);
    L13.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L14 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L14.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L14.setLocation(5, 670);
    L14.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L15 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L15.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L15.setLocation(5, 733);
    L15.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L16 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L16.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L16.setLocation(5, 796);
    L16.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L17 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L17.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L17.setLocation(5, 859);
    L17.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L18 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L18.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L18.setLocation(5, 922);
    L18.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L19 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L19.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L19.setLocation(5, 980);
    L19.setSize(2000, 20);

    /**              NEW ENDS HERE                      **/ /**              NEW ENDS HERE                      **/ /**              NEW ENDS HERE                      **/

    panel.add(L1); //keep
    panel.add(L2); //keep
    panel.add(L3); //keep
    panel.add(L4); //keep
    panel.add(L5); //keep
    panel.add(L6); //keep
    panel.add(L7); //keep
    panel.add(L8); //keep
    panel.add(L9); //keep
    panel.add(L10); //keep
    panel.add(L11); //keep
    panel.add(L12); //keep
    panel.add(L13); //keep
    panel.add(L14); //keep
    panel.add(L15); //keep
    panel.add(L16); //keep
    panel.add(L17); //keep
    panel.add(L18); //keep
    panel.add(L19); //keep

    panel.setVisible(true); //keep

    frame.setVisible(true); //keep
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 1000)); //keep
    frame.setResizable(false); //keep
    frame.setTitle("Quiz Generator (Alpha)"); //keep

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);} //keep


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static void showResults() { //keep
    //show results
    //fix by changing what panel is displayed + changing the size of the JFrame
}

public Results_GUI() {

frame = new JFrame();

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    panel.setLayout(null);

    L1 = new JLabel("RESULTS"); //keep
    L1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L1.setSize(1000, 20);
    L1.setLocation(245, 10);

    JLabel L2 = new JLabel("Author: " + author); //keep
    L2.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
    L2.setLocation(380, 950);
    L2.setSize(200, 20);

    JLabel L3 = new JLabel(version); //keep
    L3.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
    L3.setLocation(5, 950);
    L3.setSize(200, 20);


    /**              NEW STARTS HERE                      **/ /**              NEW STARTS HERE                      **/ /**              NEW STARTS HERE                      **/


    JLabel L4 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L4.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L4.setLocation(5, 40);
    L4.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L5 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L5.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L5.setLocation(5, 103);
    L5.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L6 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L6.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L6.setLocation(5, 166);  //completed
    L6.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L7 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L7.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L7.setLocation(5, 229);
    L7.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L8 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L8.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L8.setLocation(5, 292); 
    L8.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L9 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L9.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L9.setLocation(5, 355);
    L9.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L10 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L10.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L10.setLocation(5, 418); //completed
    L10.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L11 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L11.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L11.setLocation(5, 481);
    L11.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L12 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L12.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L12.setLocation(5, 544);
    L12.setSize(20000, 20);

    JLabel L13 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L13.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L13.setLocation(5, 607);
    L13.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L14 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L14.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L14.setLocation(5, 670);
    L14.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L15 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L15.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L15.setLocation(5, 733);
    L15.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L16 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L16.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L16.setLocation(5, 796);
    L16.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L17 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L17.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L17.setLocation(5, 859);
    L17.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L18 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L18.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L18.setLocation(5, 922);
    L18.setSize(2000, 20);

    JLabel L19 = new JLabel(author); //NEW
    L19.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    L19.setLocation(5, 980);
    L19.setSize(2000, 20);

    /**              NEW ENDS HERE                      **/ /**              NEW ENDS HERE                      **/ /**              NEW ENDS HERE                      **/

    panel.add(L1); //keep
    panel.add(L2); //keep
    panel.add(L3); //keep
    panel.add(L4); //keep
    panel.add(L5); //keep
    panel.add(L6); //keep
    panel.add(L7); //keep
    panel.add(L8); //keep
    panel.add(L9); //keep
    panel.add(L10); //keep
    panel.add(L11); //keep
    panel.add(L12); //keep
    panel.add(L13); //keep
    panel.add(L14); //keep
    panel.add(L15); //keep
    panel.add(L16); //keep
    panel.add(L17); //keep
    panel.add(L18); //keep
    panel.add(L19); //keep

    panel.setVisible(true); //keep

    frame.setVisible(true); //keep
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 1000)); //keep
    frame.setResizable(false); //keep
    frame.setTitle("Quiz Generator (Alpha)"); //keep

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);} //keep


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static void showResultsCalled() { //keep
    //show results
    //fix by changing what panel is displayed + changing the size of the JFrame
}

}
```

So essentially what I want to do is when the button is pressed 5 times, I want to add the JPanel from the Results_GUI class and remove the one from the Initial_GUI class.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: *"but **BEFORE** you downvote the question, let me explain."* It was up to you to add an MCVE / SSCCE **BEFORE** I down-voted.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to switch between fixed panels, I suggest to use [card layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a null pointer exception because `Results_GUI.panel` is not initialized.
Initialize it before using like `new Results_GUI()`.